# After each drag and drop insert a new row to the table to accept the next drag and drop - my code only works on the first drag and drop

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

When I drag and drop an item I want to insert a new row into the table, at the end, to accept the next drag and drop. In my code below this only works once. On the second drag and drop the new row is not inserted into the table. The last line of code below inserts the new row:

```
($('#activity2Tablebody').append("<td><div class='droppableItem'></td>");).

function makeDraggable() {
    $('.dragabbleItem').draggable({
        stack: ".dragabbleItem",
        cursor: 'pointer',
        helper: 'clone',
        drag: function( event, ui ) {
            //Make the row/field being dragged to droppable
            makeDroppable();
        }
    });
}

function makeDraggableRemove() {
    //This item will be deleted when dragged
    $('.dragabbleRemove').draggable({
        cursor: 'pointer',
        drag: function( event, ui ) {
            //Remove this row from the table
            $(this).remove();           
        }
    });
}

function makeDroppable() {
    $('.droppableItem').droppable({
        hoverClass: 'hovered',
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            var droppable = $(this);
            var draggable = ui.draggable;
            alert( 'The item with ID "' + draggable.attr('id') + '" was dropped onto me!' );
            // Move draggable into droppable
            var drag = $('.droppableItem').has(ui.draggable).length ? draggable : draggable.clone().draggable({
                revert: "invalid",
                stack: ".dragabbleItem",
                helper: 'clone'
            });
            //Add the dragged item to the row/field
            drag.appendTo(droppable);
            //Stop the dropped item from being draggable
            drag.draggable('disable');
            //Format the row/field dropped into with a blue background
            droppable.css({top: '5px', left: '5px', background: '#B0C4DE'});
            //Do not allow another item to be dropped into this row/field
            droppable.droppable('disable');
            //If this row/filed is dragged then remove it
            droppable.addClass("dragabbleRemove");
            makeDraggableRemove();
            //Add a new row/field to drag to
            $('#activity2Tablebody').append("<td><div class='droppableItem'></td>");
        } 
    });
}
```

Comment: Perhaps not related to the problem, but you append **<td>** to the table body. Should append **<tr><td>**

Comment: Hi Benny, that is the answer :-) Please add as your answer so I can up vote and tick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should append to the table body `<tr><td>` - table row and cell, not only `<td>`